# Is it possible to convert an Erlang Atom into a numeric value?

Tags: hash, erlang

As far as I am aware, atoms in Erlang are stored as indices into the Atom Table, ie they are essentially numbers.

I want to calculate a hash value for a list which contains atoms, so ideally I would want to convert the atoms into numbers for processing. I am aware that the numbers can vary between VMs, but that is not relevant for my use case -- I am just looking for an easy way to convert them into numerical values.

I guess I could convert them back into lists or binaries (but those are then the lists of the characters making up the name) and use those values instead to calculate a hash value (essentially of the *name* of the atom).

So my questions are:

1. Is it at all possible to access the internal (numerical) value of an atom?
2. Should I not worry about this at all and instead use the `atom_to_list` function, which will probably only be marginally slower?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if there's a way to access the atom table index, but if you want to get a hash value for an Erlang term, one easy way is [`erlang:phash2/1`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#phash2-1):

```
> erlang:phash2(foo).
27999
```

The hash value is based on the name of the atom, so it's similar to your `atom_to_list` idea.

Comment: Ah, I was looking for a function `hash`, and couldn't find one in the docs...!